# how do I click a keep button in download page chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

hey I need to click every enregistrer ( keep ) button in this page but I cant find the selector for it

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I tried to right click your screenshot and inspect elements to figure out a selector.  For some reason, I couldn't find one.

Comment: I tried inspecting and copying the selector but it doesnt work @Taplar

Comment: You're missing my point.  That picture doesn't help explain what the issue is.  And it's forcing me to go to an off site resource to try to identify what your problem is and potentially find a solution.  Problem on StackOverflow are expected to be self contained.

Comment: Clearly you are doing something wrong but your question shows little effort in trying to explain your issue. Try adding more information to the question directly instead of just pasting an image. Try adding: the chromium browser you are using + version, which selector you tried using already, what version of 'puppeteer' you are using, what kind of output or possible error message do you get from 'puppeteer', etc.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot scrape a **chrome://** url, and the "keep" is a security feature of chrome. So automating it is not possible as well.

If this is puppeteer, you can try to allow downloads normally,

```
await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {
  behavior: 'allow',
  downloadPath: '/path/to/some/directory',
});
```